# leaking shower faucet

Tags: shower, faucet, leaking

The hot water in my shower leaks and I'm trying to remove the stem but I don't see a hexagon type nut to unscrew.

[image: Tap / Faucet insert attached to pipe]

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to unscrew that inner unit.  Use mole grips or similar just before the brass thread.

There appears to be a notch in the brass ring, there is probably a specific tool to engage in that to turn it.

This is a similar unit, but it does have a hexagonal nut.  If you get the unit out, replace it with a new one.

[image: Typical tap / faucet inner unit]

Comment: When you refer to "inner unit" are you referring to the dark part just before the brass? I'm unscrewing the dark part and not the brass, correct?

Comment: Not just the dark part, the brass too.  I've added an image to the answer of a typical replacement unit.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to remove it with wrench similar to the mole grip.

Comment: Is there a brand or model number I should look for as the replacement? Thanks

Comment: @Dani: Impossible to say from a picture.  They come in different sizes.  Either measure it carefully and search online (I did this) or take the dead one to a builders merchant and see what they have.

Answer (score 0):

There are flats on the valve body. There's one visible here, and there will be another on the opposing side. Use an adjustable wrench, sliplock plier, or other similar tool.

[image]